# TabControl SelectedContent not returning the current selected TabItem content

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, tabcontrol

Currently I have a TabControl with several TabItems. Each TabItem has a DataGrid inside. I wanted to format these DataGrids (cell colors, column widths, etc) all at once but I found I can't because all the DataGrids from the hidden tabs would return null properties. In this case, I tried to make a work around where I would select programmatically (or manually with the mouse) the tabs before formatting the DataGrid. But now I'm up against a "strange" behavior:

```
    private void LeftTabs_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    Console.WriteLine(LeftTabs.SelectedIndex);
    var currentDataGrid = (DataGrid)LeftTabs.SelectedContent;
    Console.WriteLine(currentDataGrid.Name);
}
```

The selected index returns the correct tab index, but the content it's not updated. 
Let's say Tab 1 is selected and then I click on Tab 2. It returns me the Tab 2 index and the Tab 1 DataGrid name.

This behavior prevents me from editing the select tab's DataGrid because even if I try to access it directly by it's object, all the properties return null.

This is the TabControl, item and DataGrids XAML code:

```
<TabControl Name="LeftTabs" Margin="0,0,0,0"  Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" SelectionChanged="LeftTabs_SelectionChanged">
        <TabItem>
            <TabItem.Header>Conditions</TabItem.Header>
            <DataGrid x:Name="DataGrid_Conditions" SelectedCellsChanged="DataGrid_Conditions_SelectedCellsChanged" ColumnWidth="80" ItemsSource="{Binding}" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"   VerticalAlignment="Top" SelectionChanged="ConditionsSelected" />
        </TabItem>
        <TabItem>
            <TabItem.Header>Signals</TabItem.Header>
            <DataGrid x:Name="DataGrid_Signals" ColumnWidth="80" ItemsSource="{Binding}" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"  VerticalAlignment="Top" SelectionChanged="SignalsSelected" />
        </TabItem>
    </TabControl>
```

EDIT:
To be more clear I'll minimize the scenario.
TabItem1 - Has DataGrid_Conditions inside;
TabItem2 - Has DataGrid_Signals inside.

Here is another code that I try to run when I manually or programmatically select a tab:

```
DataGridRow Row = (DataGridRow)DataGrid_Signals.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(ID);
```

What happens is, If I click on tab2 this code doesn't for tab2's Grid. Instead it works for the previous tab(1) Grid.
The LeftTabs.SelectedContent is the only property not being updated.

Answer (score 1):

I can't seem to reproduce your issue. "DataGrid_Signals" should be printed out when you selecte the second tab. You may also get a reference to the currently selected `TabItem` from the `SelectionChangedEventArgs`:

```
private void LeftTabs_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    Debug.WriteLine(LeftTabs.SelectedIndex);
    TabItem tabItem = e.AddedItems[0] as TabItem;
    var currentDataGrid = (DataGrid)tabItem.Content;
    Debug.WriteLine(currentDataGrid.Name);
}
```

> In this example despite it indeed printing "DataGrid_Signals" when I try to get anything from the grid's object, it just comes null as it was in a hidden.

This is because it has not yet been loaded. You can force it to render by measure and arrange it:

```
private void LeftTabs_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (IsLoaded)
    {
        TabItem tabItem = e.AddedItems[0] as TabItem;
        var currentDataGrid = (DataGrid)tabItem.Content;
        currentDataGrid.Measure(new Size(currentDataGrid.ActualWidth, currentDataGrid.ActualHeight));
        currentDataGrid.Arrange(new Rect(0, 0, currentDataGrid.ActualWidth, currentDataGrid.ActualHeight));
        //...
    }
}
```

Comment: Your code returns the current DataGrid correctly but the problem is that the LeftTabs.SelectedContent still returns the previous tab's Grid, what makes it impossible to edit. In this example despite it indeed printing "DataGrid_Signals" when I try to get anything from the grid's object, it just comes null as it was in a hidden.

Comment: That's because it hasn't been loaded yet.

Comment: sure sure, the whole problem here is why this happens and how to load it programmatically.

Comment: Unfortunately it still does not work. Right after your code if, for example, I run a code to get a DataRow (see my edit on post) from the grid I suposedely clicked it returns me null, but if I ask this same DataRow from the previous grid, it returns me correctly. So somehow your code doesn't update the TabControl selected content.

Comment: @RubenC. No. `e.AddedItems[0]` certainly references the newly selected `TabItem`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/180009/discussion-between-rubenc-and-mm8).

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug, fixed in .NET 4.7.1 but quirked so that apps targeting 4.7 or below still get the old behavior.  See the [breaking change announcement](https://github.com/Microsoft/dotnet/blob/master/Documentation/compatibility/wpf-tabcontrol-selectionchanged-and-selectedcontent.md) for details.